# How to install psyocpg2 with poetry using a python 3.10.8 provided by pyenv?

Tags: psycopg2, python-poetry, pyenv

I'm new to poetry and pyenv, and I'm trying to make them work together on my django project.

I first when for poetry with my system python and it all worked well.

```
poetry init
poetry add django djangorestframework whitenoise gunicorn django-heroku
```

After that, I tried to install python 3.10.8 since it is the preferred version for Heroku.
And I used pyenv for that:

```
pyenv install 3.10.8
poetry env use ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/bin/python
```

After that, I can see two env in the folder:

```
$ poetry env list
paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10 (Activated)
paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.8
```

I removed `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` files to start fresh.
Poetry init when well, but when I tried to add dependencies I had problems with psycopg2.

Trying to solve the issue I tried installing `sudo apt install libpq-dev`  but it was already installed.

Adding `poetry add psycopg2-binary` went well, but I still have issues.

Here is the full error tracer:

```
$ poetry add django djangorestframework whitenoise gunicorn django-heroku
Using version ^4.1.2 for Django
Using version ^3.14.0 for djangorestframework
Using version ^6.2.0 for whitenoise
Using version ^20.1.0 for gunicorn
Using version ^0.3.1 for django-heroku

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.5s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing psycopg2 (2.9.5): Failed

  CalledProcessError

  Command '['/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10', '--no-deps', '/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/76/35/37/5c9e40406173ab076bef7fe83c7f5488acf226922bd1155bdf857b9b92/psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

  at /usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:516 in run
       512│             # We don't call process.wait() as .__exit__ does that for us.
       513│             raise
       514│         retcode = process.poll()
       515│         if check and retcode:
    →  516│             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
       517│                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
       518│     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
       519│ 
       520│ 

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--use-pep517', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--prefix', '/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10', '--no-deps', '/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/76/35/37/5c9e40406173ab076bef7fe83c7f5488acf226922bd1155bdf857b9b92/psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/76/35/37/5c9e40406173ab076bef7fe83c7f5488acf226922bd1155bdf857b9b92/psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [64 lines of output]
        /tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
          warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
        running dist_info
        creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info
        writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
        writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        adding license file 'LICENSE'
        writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-gpkmbva3/psycopg2-2.9.5.dist-info'
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
            main()
          File "/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "/home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/paint-projects-yd5RS8WI-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 377, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            self.run_setup()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 483, in run_setup
            super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
            exec(code, locals())
          File "<string>", line 550, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
            return run_commands(dist)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 101, in run
            bdist_wheel = self.get_finalized_command('bdist_wheel')
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 305, in get_finalized_command
            cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 859, in get_command_obj
            klass = self.get_command_class(command)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 954, in get_command_class
            self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
          File "/home/miguel/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
            module = import_module(match.group('module'))
          File "/home/miguel/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 26, in <module>
            from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-2ln2ngiu/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 41, in <module>
            import ctypes
          File "/home/miguel/.pyenv/versions/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
            from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: metadata-generation-failed
  
  × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for details.
  

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1476 in _run
      1472│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1473│                     command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=env, **kwargs
      1474│                 )
      1475│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1476│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1477│ 
      1478│         return decode(output)
      1479│ 
      1480│     def execute(self, bin: str, *args: str, **kwargs: Any) -> int:

The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  PoetryException

  Failed to install /home/miguel/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts/76/35/37/5c9e40406173ab076bef7fe83c7f5488acf226922bd1155bdf857b9b92/psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz

  at ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/utils/pip.py:51 in pip_install
       47│ 
       48│     try:
       49│         return environment.run_pip(*args)
       50│     except EnvCommandError as e:
    →  51│         raise PoetryException(f"Failed to install {path.as_posix()}") from e
       52│
```

Is there anything I need to consider when using poetry and pyenv?

Comment: Have you left any code editor open for a long time? I faced the same problem when I try to add the same package via VS Code, the program has been running for a long period of time, So I think the cache is causing the problem